# How to install GD library with Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, gd, strawberry-perl, gnuwin32

I am attempting to install the GD library using Strawberry perl and [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gd.htm). However, when I enter "install GD" in the CPAN shell, the following message appears:

`'gdlib-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. **UNRECOVERABLE ERROR** Could not find gdlib-config in the search path. Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher.`

I believe perl is having difficulty locating the GD library installed at C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin, but I am not sure how to fix this. I am still new to perl, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is confirmed on  [cpan testers](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.cpan.testers/2008/05/msg1430597.html).

Looks like you need to  [manually compile and install](http://www.libgd.org/FAQ_C_Compile) gdlib.

Answer (score 2):

If you make sure that `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin` is in your `PATH` variable (`$PATH`? `%PATH%`? I'm not sure which one GnuWin32 uses) before you start CPAN, the installer should find the `gdlib-config` program and you will at least be able to get through that step of the installation.

Comment: I had already done that, but it still wouldn't find gdlib-config.

Answer (score 2):

Run 'Makefile.PL' manually. It will show you list of parameters. Try running it with parameter "-lib_gd_path".

GD may be included in Strawberry 5.10.1.0 beta. A good place to ask is irc://irc.perl.org/#win32 IRC channel.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Strawberry Perl are you using? I am using the one bundled with [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) and GD came with it:

```
C:\opt> perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 0) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.2, archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
    uname='Win32 padre 5.10.0.7.beta_1 #1 20 i386'
...
```

And:

```
C:\opt> perl -MGD -Mfeature=say -e "say $GD::VERSION"
2.44
```

Comment: 'perl -MGD -E "say $GD::VERSION"' is shorter

Comment: @Alexandr Yeah, well, I got called names for using that once, mainly because "latest features" is an ambiguous concept, so I explicitly say what I mean these days.

Comment: `perl -MGD -le "print $GD::VERSION"` - The `-l` adds a newline to each `print`, so the `say` feature isn't needed on the command line.