# Install GD Library on RedHat machine for twiki

Tags: perl, redhat, gdlib, twiki

My ultimate goal is to run a [twiki](http://twiki.org/) website for my research group.

I have space on RedHat server that is running Apache, etc., but upon which I do not have root access. Since I cannot install perl modules with the current permissions, I've decided to manually install a local version of perl. Got that working no problem. The following modules are required to get twiki to work:

- FreezeThaw - [http://search.cpan.org/~ilyaz/FreezeThaw](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eilyaz/FreezeThaw)
- CGI::Session - [http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Session](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emarkstos/CGI-Session)
- Error - [http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Error](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eshlomif/Error)
- GD - [http://search.cpan.org/~lds/GD](http://search.cpan.org/%7Elds/GD)
- HTML::Tree - [http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epetek/HTML-Tree)
- Time-modules - [http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Time-modules](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emuir/Time-modules)

I have installed FreezeThaw, CGI, Error, and it fails on GD with the following error:

> **UNRECOVERABLE ERROR** Could not find gdlib-config in the search path.
>
> Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher. If you want to try to
>
> compile anyway, please rerun this script with the option --ignore_missing_gd.

In searching for how to get around this newest obstacle, I found a previous SO question: [How to install GD library with Strawberry Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627143/how-to-install-gd-library-with-strawberry-perl) asked about installing this and the top answer [suggested manually compiling](http://www.libgd.org/FAQ_C_Compile) gdlib. You'll note, however, that that link is broken. The base site: http://www.libgd.org/ is basically down saying to go to the project's [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd) page.

So I got the tarball from that page and am trying to install it. The following problems occur when I follow the instructions included. README.TXT says: "If the sources have been fetched from CVS, run bootstrap.sh [options]."

Running bootstrap.sh yields:

> configure.ac:64: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
>
> configure.ac:10: required directory ./config does not exist cp: cannot
>
> create regular file `config/config.guess': No such file or directory
>
> configure.ac:11: installing `config/config.guess' configure.ac:11:
>
> error while copying cp: cannot create regular file
>
> `config/config.sub': No such file or directory configure.ac:11:
>
> installing `config/config.sub' configure.ac:11:     error while
>
> copying cp: cannot create regular file `config/install-sh': No such
>
> file or directory configure.ac:28: installing `config/install-sh'
>
> configure.ac:28:     error while copying cp: cannot create regular
>
> file `config/missing': No such file or directory configure.ac:28:
>
> installing `config/missing' configure.ac:28:     error while copying
>
> configure.ac:577: required file `config/Makefile.in' not found
>
> configure.ac:577: required file `config/gdlib-config.in' not found
>
> configure.ac:577: required file `test/Makefile.in' not found
>
> Makefile.am:14: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
>
> Makefile.am:14:   The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add
>
> `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' Makefile.am:14:   to` configure.ac' and run
>
> `aclocal' and` autoconf' again. Makefile.am:14:   If `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL'
>
> is in `configure.ac', make sure Makefile.am:14:   its definition is in
>
> aclocal's search path. cp: cannot create regular file
>
> `config/depcomp': No such file or directory Makefile.am: installing
>
> `config/depcomp' Makefile.am:     error while copying Failed

And it says I should also install the following 3rd party libraries:

1. zlib, available from http://www.gzip.org/zlib/
   Data compression library
2. libpng, available from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/
   Portable Network Graphics library; requires zlib
3. FreeType 2.x, available from http://www.freetype.org/
   Free, high-quality, and portable font engine
4. JPEG library, available from http://www.ijg.org/
   Portable JPEG compression/decompression library
5. XPM, available from http://koala.ilog.fr/lehors/xpm.html
   X Pixmap library

Which I am ignoring for now.

Switching to the generic instructions it says follow the advice in the INSTALL file; which says: "cd to the directory containing the package's source code and type ./configure to configure the package for your system." Which flat does not work: I've cd'ed into every directory of the tarball and running that command does nothing.

So, trying to install twiki required me to install perl, which required me to install the perl modules: FreezeThaw, CGI, Error, HTML, Time-modules, and GD -- which itself required me to install gdlib -- which further suggested I install zlib, libpng, FreeType 2.x, JPEG library, and XPM. And of course, I'm stuck at the installing gdlib stage.

**My question is**: what other process can possibly demean humanity to such a level? I cannot fathom the depths of cruelty that lay ahead of me as I dive ever deeper into this misery onion. Should I just end it all? Can meaning be brought from this madness? Will the sun come up tomorrow, and if so, does it even matter?

But seriously, any suggestions on what to do differently/better would be much appreciated -- I can't remember what a child's laughter sounds like anymore.

Comment: Just a suggestion: maybe better to ask your system administrator with root access to install all these libraries (btw, required by a lot of software) for you; is it possible?

Comment: Might be... I'll probably end up sending him a link to this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install the package `gd-devel`, it contains `/usr/bin/gdlib-config`.

Comment: If the proposal [Easy installation of non-CPAN dependencies](http://news.perlfoundation.org/2012/05/2012q2-grant-proposal-easy-ins.html) by [chorny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13467/alexandr-ciornii) is granted and completed, these sort of beginner problems will dwindle drastically. Community, please share this.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do that. I thought the RPM would be here: http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/6.2/x86_64/Packages/gd-devel-2.0.35-10.el6.x86_64.html -- but file not found. Also, the link to the http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page also doesn't work. Can you please link to a place that has a tarball of this gd-devel?

Comment: [yum install](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Installing.html)

Comment: The workaround is to compile everything yourself under a directory prefix that you control (e.g. your home directory), as you attempted in the question.

Comment: You got the wrong tarball, since you are not a GD developer, you should not check out `tip`, but the latest release tagged with a version number, e.g. [GD_2_0_34RC1.tar.gz](https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/get/GD_2_0_34RC1.tar.gz). I see that openSUSE has a more recent one: [gd-2.0.36.RC1.tar.bz2](https://api.opensuse.org/public/source/openSUSE:12.1/gd/gd-2.0.36.RC1.tar.bz2). Plain `./configure` works, without the need to bootstrap.

Comment: Simple ubuntu command that worked for me: `sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev`

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libgd2-xpm-dev build-essential
```

Comment: It won't because 1) I don't have root access (so sudo is out) 2) CentOS is not debian based (so apt-get is out).